# Ignore parameters from download url in Matomo statistics

Tags: matomo

It is possible to ignore GET parameters form "normal" urls in Matomo, but I can't find the option to remove parameters from download links:

Examples:

```
www.domain.com/index.php?param=foo&file=myfile.pdf
www.domain.com/index.php?param=bar&file=myfile.pdf
```

Now I want to exclude the parameter `param` in the statistics, that the above example will be counted as the same url. Is this possible?

Comment: Does this FAQ help?
https://matomo.org/faq/how-to/faq_81/

Comment: No, unfortunatelly this does not help. This effects "normal" urls only.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure this in the Matomo settings:

> You can easily ignore a number of parameters from the URLs, and prevent them from appearing in the “Behavior > Pages” report. Login as the Super User, go to Administration > Manage Websites > Global list of Query URL parameters to exclude field.
>
> https://matomo.org/faq/how-to/faq_81/

Comment: Unfortunately this excludes parameters from "normal" urls only (Behaviour -> Pages), but not from downloads (Behaviour -> Downloads).